# why JSON.stringify is adding extra ""

Tags: javascript, json

My application receives the following message from the server

`got error from the Observable:  {result: "error", additional-info: "", http-status: "401", http-status-text: "Unauthorized"}`

I parse it into a variable

```
error:ServerResponseAPI
```

If I do `JSON.stringify(error['additional-info'])`, I notice that the result is `""""` instead of `""`

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`""` is an empty string, which is valid JSON (any single string is valid JSON). If you use `JSON.stringify` on an empty string, it will stringify/serialize the provided value into JSON. In this case that's an empty string, so it will give you a string of quotes. This is why you might see `'""'`, or `""""` when logging the value. It's a string that contains a JSON representation of an empty string (which is the two quotes).

`JSON.stringify('a')` will give you `'"a"'`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The outer quotes is to indicate that this content is inside a string.

Your json content is an empty string represented inside a real string, it could be presented with escapes: `"\"\""`.

If `error['additional-info']` is null, `JSON.stringify(error['additional-info'])` would return `"null"`. The content in this case is the `null` value, without quotes.

`JSON.stringify` will never return an empty string.